# Prove that any circuit contains a cycle

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, intuition

This is a practice question (not HW)

Prove that any circuit in a graph must contain a cycle AND that any circuit that is not a cycle contains at least two cycles.

Note : This is for a  first course in Graph theory

I have answer to this question but the answer raises more questions.
ANSWER: Suppose the vertices of the circuit are $v_0,v_1,...v_n,v_0$. Consider all subcircuits of the form $v_i,...v_n,v_i$. The subcircuit that uses the fewest number of vertices is a cycle (my Q: BUT WHY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this smallest circuit $C$ is not a cycle.  Then it must repeat a vertex $v_j$.  So write the circuit as $v_i C v_j C v_j C v_i$ (that is, follow the cycle from $v_i$ to $v_j$ around back to $v_j$ and back to $v_i$).

$v_j C v_j$ is a smaller circuit, contradicting the choice of $C$.

Your approach to the proof was correct: you just needed to look for a contradiction.  The combination of looking for a graph satisfying some minimal or maximal property together with a proof by contradiction is extremely powerful in graph theory.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I have done some proofs by contradiction but in this case I have only one question. How does showing that $v_jCv_j$ is a smaller circuit also prove that C is  a cycle.

Comment: @KjTada The scheme for our proof is as follows: We have a smallest circuit.  If it's not a cycle, then we can find a smaller circuit.  $\perp$.  I think you might be mistaking the direction of the implication here.  No cycle $\implies$ the existence of a smaller circuit; the other direction does not matter for the purposes of the proof.